# How to enable sqlsrv - PDO drivers in xampp ubuntu?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

> Error : PDOException could not find driver

Actually I am facing error this while working with laravel and mssql .

For that purpose I want enable sqlsrv in  PDO drivers .

[PDO Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwFwx.png)

In this image PDO drivers contain mysql, pgsql, sqlite but not sqlsrv .
So How I can fix it ?

Comment: have you visited this link? if not, then please http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess your PHP environment doesn't have **PDO** extension installed.

To install **pdo** extension, open terminal and type the below command.

First check which version of PHP is installed, to check the PHP version, type below command :

```
$ php -v
```

Suppose you have **php7.1** installed, then to install **pdo** for your version type below

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-pdo
```

Restart you **apache** server :

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

See below snap:

[image: php -v]

After entering the command, press **tab** to see all the possible commands as shown in the snapshot.

Comment: thanks but actually I already install it . Still Not working 
see image: https://imgur.com/a/Nc4Agup

Comment: After entering the command, try pressing tab to see list of available commands on your system, I have added a snapshot for your reference in the answer.

Comment: sorry actually  not working , still facing same issue